Tangent problem involving orthocenter and circumcenter in a triangle
Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle inscribed the circle $(O)$ with three altitudes $AD, BE, CF$, orthocenter $H$. The tangent of $(O)$ at $A$ intersects $BC$ at $S$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$, $K$ be the orthogonal projection of $H$ on $AM$. Prove that $SK$ is the tangent of the circumcircle of $\triangle BHC$.

My attempts:

$HDKM$, $BHKC$ are inscribed.
The circles $(G)$ and $(O)$ have the same radius.

I think this is a well-known result in Euclidean geometry but I don't remember how to solve it. Could you please help me to solve this problem? Thanks

Assuming "my attempts" refers to things that you've proved (rather than just guessed), can you state the proofs?

My first question would be, why is it even guaranteed that $K$ is between $A$ and $M$?

@Ian: Yes, you can prove that $\widehat{AHM}>\widehat{AHC}>90^o$ so $\triangle AHM$ is obtuse at $H$ and so $K$ lies between $A$ and $M$.

ABC doesn't actually have to be acute to get the result (but if $\angle A$ is obtuse then $K$ isn't between $A$ and $M$ so the picture is rather different). So I guess my question isn't really relevant.

My first idea, given that $M$ is relevant to the definition of $K$ but the altitudes don't really seem to have much to do with anything otherwise, is to view $H$ as the circumcenter of the medial triangle instead of as the orthocenter of the original.

@CalvinLin: Yes, surely I can prove them, but is it important here (to prove that I can prove them?) For example, let $J$ be the intersection of $HK$ and $BC$ then $E, F, J$ also colinear, then $JE\cdot JF = JB\cdot JC$ ; $JE\cdot JF = JD\cdot JM$ then $JH\cdot JK = JB \cdot JC$, you get $BHKC$ is inscribed

@anonimo Yes please! It shows how much you know. In my opinion, your comment shows that you know quite a bit of geometry, which allows me to explore more complicated approaches, or skip some basic details. $\quad$ Note that in my solution, I used both of your claims, so please prove them (by editing the question).

This proof works backwards to motivate the approach, but that makes the flow very disjointed.
Conversely, for the forwards proof, the steps might seem random, though the proof will read more smoothly (basically just lemmas and corollaries).
I'm skipping the proof of / assuming that $K$ lies on $(G)$, which OP claims is true.

WTS $ \angle OAK = \angle MKG$

Suppose that holds. Let $ AO$ intersect $KG$ at $P$, then $PA = PK$ as we have an isosceles triangle.
Let $(P)$ be the circle centered at $P$ with radius $PA$.  Consider the circles $(P), (O), (G)$.
$(P)$ and $(O)$ have radical axis "tangent at $A$", $(O)$ and $(G)$ have radical axis $BC$, so their radical center is $S$.
$(P)$ and  $(G)$ have radical axis "tangent at $K$". The radical axis goes through the radical center, so $SK$ is tangential to $(G)$  as desired.


WTS $SC$ is tangential to circumcircle of $ACK$.

Suppose that holds. Let $ \beta = \angle ABC$ per standard terminology. Then $\angle OAK  = \angle CAK - ( 90^\circ - \beta)  = \angle CAK - \angle BCF$.
Let $\angle MKG = \theta$. Then $\angle HKG = 90^\circ - \theta, \angle HGK = 2 \theta, \angle KCH = \theta$.
Observe that $ \angle KCH + \angle BCF = \angle KCB$, which by alternate segment theorem, is equal to $\angle CAK$. Hence $ \angle OAK = \angle MKG$


WTS $MB \times MC = MK \times MA$

Suppose that holds, then $MC^2 = MK \times MA$ so $SC$ is tangential to circumcircle of $ACK$.


WTS $(O)$ and $(G)$ have equal radius

Suppose that holds, then $(O)$ and $(G)$ are reflections through the midpoint $M$ of their common chord $BC$.
Reflect $K$ about $M$ to $K'$. Since $K$ is on $(G)$, so $K'$ is on $(O)$.
Thus by power of a point, $ MB \times MC = MA \times MK' = MA \times MK $


OP claims that $(O)$ and $(G)$ have equal radius, hence we are done.

Note

This proof does somewhat depend on the diagram. In particular, I'm assuming that the circumcenter is within $\triangle MAC$.

I'm too lazy to draw up the other cases, and I assume that a similar proof works.
We might be able to work around this via directed angles and line segments.


This feels more convoluted than I'd like it to be.

I won't be surprised if there's a proof that uses point $J$, which OP has shown is the intersection of $EF, HK, BC$. (We could prove this by showing that $J$ is the radical center of 3 circles, whose radical axis are these lines.)


The line $SK$ has very little relationship from the initial setup, which is why the first thing that I did was to avoid having to depend on it.

Another approach might be to show that $SA = SK$, like via angle chasing. I decided not to pursue it as I wanted to avoid $SK$ altogether.


Per my comment, I'm leaving it to OP / the reader to show that

$(O)$ and $(G)$ have the same radius.
$K$ lies on $(G)$.

This requires a bit of work. OP stated an incomplete approach in the comments. The approach that I like finds 3 circles with radical center $J$ and thus $JD \cdot JM= JF \cdot JE = JH \cdot JK = JB \cdot JC$.




If you let $X$ be the midpoint of $AH$ and $Y$ be the midpoint of $AK$, then the nine point circle is DEFMXY, with $XY \perp AM$. Hence $SXY$ is a straight line.

Alternatively, if we should show that $SXY$ is  straight line (EG By Menelaus or $MJ/MS = MK/MY$), then it's perpendicular bisector of $AK$ hence $SA = SK$.




I think the flow is confusing here. #1 is "if we could show these angles are equal then this is why we would be done with the whole problem", #2 is "if we could show this other tangency relationship then this is why we would have X". I think those are great candidates for backwards style because the utility of these lemmata is not exactly obvious. But #3 and #4 are really just proving $SC$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $ACK$, and they're not particularly long or convoluted. I think turning to the forward direction right after #2 would be more legible.

@Ian #3 is "if we could show Z then this is why we would have Y" and #4 is "we show Z". In fact, #4 would have been "If we could show equal radius, then we have Z".  I mainly came up with these only via working backwards + wishful thinking. $\quad$ Actually, I'm going to introduce #5. lol.

I guess my objection is more related to the claims about the equal radii and $K$ being on circle $G$ not being inside the exposition of the answer, which made #4 in the original writeup seem shorter than it really was. But this is appropriate in the context of the post in general (I agree it would be good if OP could write up the gaps you're leaving into the OP).

Your edit helps a surprisingly large amount.
